# BufferedReader can't recognize lines if I paste some lines. How can I input lines?

Tags: java

I am solving a UVA problem named "NEWSPAPER" where I have to input several lines. I paste some lines, but the BufferedReader just recognize the first line, and thats why I am getting compile error message from UVA. I did this:

```
String sentence = null;

try 
{
    sentence = br.readLine();
} 
catch(IOException io) 
{
    System.out.println("Found exception!");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Here `br` is a `BufferedReader` type. Now, how can I solve the problem? The UVA problem no is -11340 - Newspaper.

Comment: Have you googled for 11340 - Newspaper java ?

Comment: You told Java to read a single line, so it reads just a single line. What did you expect? The method *is not called* "`readLines()`".

Comment: What's your question? BufferedReader's runtime behaviour does not cause a compile error. Please restate your question clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this if you want to read till end of file.

```
while((sentence=br.readLine())!= null){
    // Do something
}
```

**sentence = br.readLine();**

Above code will read a single line as expected.

[BufferedReader#readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.